# How to create a workspace in jupyterlab?

Tags: jupyter-lab

I jupyter lab and some notebook I would like to save this workspace.
The URL of the page is http://localhost:8888/lab
I can't find in the related documentation (https://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user/urls.html) where to create a workspace from the default one. It indicates how to clone an already existing workspace.
I usually duplicate the tab which creates automatically an additional workspace and then clones that workspace. But this approach results in a lot of workspaces in the workspace directory.

Answer (score 3):

Right after posting the answer comes. This might be useful to others though.
The url in cloning the default shows how:

http://localhost:8888/lab/workspaces/auto-f?clone

So replace `auto-f` with your desired workspace name.

Comment: I have been trying to replace `auto-f` (or whichever) with `myname` but `myname` reverts itself to a different `auto-?`. Any ideas?